# Will the humble version of halcyon 6 work on steam for linux?

Tags: steam, linux, humble-bundle, halcyon-6

Halcyon 6 in the [Humble Store](https://www.humblebundle.com/store/halcyon-6-starbase-commander?hmb_source=search_bar) says the following:

> Halcyon 6: Starbase Commander is provided via Steam key for Windows and Mac.

However, Halcyon 6 in the [Steam store](http://store.steampowered.com/app/371200/Halcyon_6_Starbase_Commander/) claims it supports linux.

If I buy a key through the Humble Store and activate it on Steam, will I be able to play it on Linux?

I assume there is just one kind of key, and as long as the Steam version supports Linux I should be fine, but the discrepancy makes me unsure.

Comment: In Steam, when you purchase a game, you can use that game on any OS that the game works on. Steam's database records that your account has obtained access to a particular title, it does not restrict which operating system you use that title on (beyond the restriction of a title simply not being available for a given operating system). If you have access to a Mac computer, a Windows computer and a Linux computer, you may have the game installed on all three simultaneously. In short: this is a failing on Humble Bundle's part - they have not kept their information up to date.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes.

As long as you get the steam key and the steam store page states that it supports steam for Linux, you should be fine.

Comment: Just gave it a try and it works! That's what I suspected, but wanted to make sure.